# Global Twig parameter transformation in Symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, twig

I have added some config parameters in config.yml like:

```
twig:
  globals:
    brands:
      'land-rover': 'Land Rover'
```

The problem that I have is that once I use this inside twig, land-rover becomes land_rover.

```
{% for slugKey, name in brands %}
    <li><a href="{{ path('getSearchResultsByBrand', {'slug': slugKey, 'edition': edition.edition}) }}">{{ name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Why is this transformation happening automatically and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/6086 and this fix: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/6367

Comment: thank you duncan. since i just needed this for one array of variables, i did a |replace in twig.

Comment: @duncan You should post that as an aswer